# flutter flutter_webview_plugin alway loading

Tags: webview, flutter

i run the code in ios simulator ,but ios alaways loading,the webview state is startLoad,but canot finishLoad,
the page always loading,the code liek this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List<Widget> titleContent = [];
titleContent.add(new Text(
  "资讯详情",
  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
));
if (!loaded) {
  titleContent.add(new CupertinoActivityIndicator());
}
titleContent.add(new Container(width: 50.0));
print(widget.id);
return new WebviewScaffold(
  url: "http://www.baidu.com",
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: titleContent,
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(
        icon: icon,
        onPressed: () {
          print('收藏');
          setState(() {
            icon = new Icon(Icons.star);
          });
        },
      ),
      new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.share),
        onPressed: () {
          print('分享');
        },
      ),
    ],
    iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  withZoom: false,
  withLocalStorage: false,
  withJavascript: true,
  withLocalUrl: true,
);
```

}

the page like : 
[the page like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaSq8.jpg)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the httpError stream. Maybe you're getting some errors, because normally it should work.

```
FlutterWebviewPlugin().onHttpError.listen((WebViewHttpError item) {
  print("   WebView    onHttpError.code: ${item.code}");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line:

```
withLocalUrl: true,
```